# Input and Ouput to ECS task in Step function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-step-functions

Have previously worked with lambda orchestration using AWS step function. This has been working very well. Setting the result_path of each lambda will pass along arguments to subsequent lambda.

However, I now need to run a fargate task and then pass along arguments from that fargate task to subsequent lambdas. I have created a python script that acts as the entrypoint in the container definition. Obviously in a lambda function the `handler(event, context)` acts as the entrypoint and by defining a `return {"return_object": "hello_world"}` its easy to pass a long a argument to the next state of the state machine.

In my case though, I have task definition with a container definition created from this Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

COPY my_script.py /my_script.py
RUN ln -s /python/my_script.py /usr/bin/my_script && \
chmod +x /python/my_script.py

ENTRYPOINT ["my_script"]
```

Hence, I am able to invoke the state machine and it will execute my_script as intended. But how do I get the output from this python script and pass it along to another state in the state machine?

I have found some documentation on how to pass along inputs, but no example of passing along outputs.

Comment: The step function does nor know about your Python script, just the ecs task. You would have to stage any output data from your script somewhere the lambda could read it,  so a file in s3, parameter store, sqs etc.

Comment: Yeah I figured, but I have not found a good way to do it yet. Any suggestions on pattern?

Comment: Depends on the context. SQS is a good pattern to pass data to a single lambda but in your description you mentioned multiple lambas and it’s not clear if you mean this to be simultaneously so possibly an SNS topic could suit you best as multiple lambdas could subscribe and get the same information at the same time. Seems to be more of an architectural issue where there are always trade offs that only  you are best placed to understand.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get output from an ECS/Fargate task, I think you have to use the [Task Token Integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-to-resource.html) instead of Run Job (Sync) which is usually recommended for Fargate tasks. You can pass the token as a container override (`"TASK_TOKEN": "$$.Task.Token"`). Then inside your image you need some logic like this:

```py
client = boto3.client('stepfunctions')
client.send_task_success(
    taskToken=os.environ["TASK_TOKEN"],
    output=output
)
```

to pass it back.